# Displaying content below a fixed header

Tags: css, html, flexbox, css-position

My page has a fixed header, I am aware that this causes **content flows to begin at the top of the page**. I've been searching for a workaround for this and nothing seems to be working, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553573/adding-elements-after-fixed-header)

Below is the code  and here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jordan_miguel/pen/wrPaRQ?editors=1100) - As you can see the content in my `article` is being displayed at the top of the page, although it is place at the bottom of my html.

**I'd appreciate an explained workaround so that I can LEARN.**

**UPDATE** - adding `padding-top:{500px}` successfully fixed this issue. Is this a recommended workaround? I was made aware of this fix [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/div-hidden-below-fixed-position-navbar-clearfix-issues-with-css).

Thanks guys!

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.inline-block-container>* {
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: white;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header .logo a img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 49px;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.menu li {
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header .menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header .menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.header .menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}

.site-content {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.banner-home {
  background: url("");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1000;
}

#intro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #020000;
  z-index: 50;
}

#intro a {
  border: 3px solid #020000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#intro li a {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #020000;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#intro li a:hover {
  background-color: #ffd800;
}
```

```html
<div id="page" class="rare-site">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="global-navigation">
      <!-- Global Header -->
      <header class="header">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="">
            <!--<img src="images/rare-logo.png">-->
            <h1>Rare Select</h1>
          </a>
        </div>
        <nav class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
            <!-- 
          -->
            <li>
              <div class="flexbox-container">
                <a href="">INFO</a>

            </li>
            <!--
          -->
            <li>
              <div class="flexbox-container">
                <a href="">NEWSLETTER</a>
              </div>
              <!--
          -->
              <li>
                <div class="flexbox-container">
                  <a href="">CONTACT</a>
              </li>
              <!--
          -->
          </ul>
      </header>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
          <!-- Content Area -->
          <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <div class="banner large-trunk">
              <div class="banner-home"></div>
              <div class="banner-overlay">
                <div id="intro">
                  <h2 class="discover"><u>The easy way to discover models.</u></h2>
                  <div id="button-container">
                    <div id="button-overlay">
                      <ul class="inline-block-container">
                        <li><a class="discover-1">I'm looking to become a model</a></li>
                        <li><a class="discover-2">I'm looking for a model</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <article id="newsletter">
              <div class="newsletter-entry">
                <section class="news-content trunk">
                  <div class="feature-box">
                    <h2>Recent News</h2>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </div>
            </article>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Since the `margin-top: 100px` already work how it is suppose to in your code sample, and also is the most used way to solve what you ask, how does it not work for you?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question clearly. `margin-top: 100px` works on the first section of content after the fixed header, my question is concerning any content following this section

Comment: I see now I misunderstood the question, so all good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have a 100px header and a `margin-top` applied to `site-content` for the content following it, as is usually done.

1. A `position: fixed` header will be taken out of the flow. So the DOM element following it will overlap.
2. A `z-index` higher that the surrounding content is given so that it comes on top (which you have done giving `wrapper` a `z-index: 99`)
3. The content following it is given a `margin-top` value. If the `height` of the header is fixed (as is the case here) you give it using CSS, if the height of the header is dynamic, you might have to opt for javascript to set the `height` dynamically.

So restrict the heights of `#global-navigation` and `.header` using `height: 100%` and add `display: flex` to the navigation `ul`. Also remove the *absolute positioning* of the *banner* and apply background image to `site-content`- see demo below:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.inline-block-container>* {
  display: -moz-inline-stack;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

#global-navigation { /* ADDED */
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 100%; /* ADDED */
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: white;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header .logo a img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 49px;
}

.site-content { /* ADDED */
  background: url("http://placehold.it/50x50");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.menu li {
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.header .menu ul {
  display: flex; /* ADDED */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header .menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.header .menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}

.site-content {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.banner-home {} /* removed absolute positioning */

#intro { /* removed absolute positioning */
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #020000;
  z-index: 50;
}

#intro a {
  border: 3px solid #020000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#intro li a {
  padding: 20px;
  color: #020000;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#intro li a:hover {
  background-color: #ffd800;
}
```

```html
<div id="page" class="rare-site">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="global-navigation">
      <!-- Global Header -->
      <header class="header">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="">
            <!--<img src="images/rare-logo.png">-->
            <h1>Rare Select</h1>
          </a>
        </div>
        <nav class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
            <!-- 
          -->
            <li>
              <div class="flexbox-container">
                <a href="">INFO</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <!--
          -->
            <li>
              <div class="flexbox-container">
                <a href="">NEWSLETTER</a>
              </div>
              <!--
          -->
              <li>
                <div class="flexbox-container">
                  <a href="">CONTACT</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <!--
          -->
          </ul>
          </nav>
      </header>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
          <!-- Content Area -->
          <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
            <div class="banner large-trunk">
              <div class="banner-home"></div>
              <div class="banner-overlay">
                <div id="intro">
                  <h2 class="discover"><u>The easy way to discover models.</u></h2>
                  <div id="button-container">
                    <div id="button-overlay">
                      <ul class="inline-block-container">
                        <li><a class="discover-1">I'm looking to become a model</a></li>
                        <li><a class="discover-2">I'm looking for a model</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <article id="newsletter">
              <div class="newsletter-entry">
                <section class="news-content trunk">
                  <div class="feature-box">
                    <h2>Recent News</h2>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </div>
            </article>
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: that isn't doing the trick unfortunately, however `body:{padding-top:200px;}` is moving the `article` content below, although I'm not sure how practical this is.

Comment: note that `#intro` is `absolute` position... why do you have it? that is why the `banner` goes above (as its translated too) and the `article` goes up...

Comment: because `#intro` contains two buttons that overlay a background image. I included the bare bare bones of the code to this question

Comment: okay, so I'm confused... so could you please check out the snippet above (I've added a demo background to `banner-home`) and explain the issue pls?

Comment: When your content changes, you may have to update the value of the `padding` - so not a general solution... what you can do is remove the `absolute` from `#intro` stretch the `main` to 100vh and add the background image to this... I'll make a demo now...

Comment: This didn't work, most likely because I didn't display the FULL code for the site I'm working on..check the edit codepen link in my question, thats where I'm applying these changes

Comment: those are just images. By the way, I gave `article` a `padding-top:{500px}` which moved the content below. I then created another `section` element below the article and it displayed correctly without me having to add `padding-top`...I don't mind doing this as I have only 3 sections & a footer on this page.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot this works perfectly, it was 3am when I asked this question so that explains why I was having a hard time understanding your answer.